# Let $A\subset B$ be an injective homomorphism of noetherian integral domains s.t. $B$ is finite as $A$-module and $A$ normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A\subset B$ be an injective homomorphism of noetherian integral domains s.t. $B$ is finitely generated as $A$-module and $A$ normal.

Suppose that the normalization $\bar B$ of $B$ is finitely generated as $A$-module. And call $F_A\subset F_B$ the induced extension of fraction fields.

(i) Prove that if $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ then $B$ is normal.

(ii) Prove that if there exists $0\neq s\in A$ such that $\Omega_{[s^{-1}]B/[s^{-1}]A}=0$ iff $F_A\subseteq F_B$ is a separable field extension.

(iii) Provide an example where $\Omega_{B/A}\neq 0$, but $B$ is normal.

(iv) Prove that there exists $0\neq s\in A$ s.t. $B[s^{-1}]=\bar B[s^{-1}]$.

I've tried in this way:

(i) I've considered the conormal sequence, with $B\cong A[X_1, ..., X_n]/(f_1,..., f_m)$, then i've got that, called $I=(f_1, ..., f_m)$, 
$$I/I^2 \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} Bdx_i\cong B\otimes_A \Omega_{A[X_1,..., X_n]/A}$$ then map is surjective. My idea was to obtain some information about maximal ideals.

(ii) Done

(iii) I've considered $R=\frac {k[X,Y]}{(Y^2-X(X-1)(X+1))}$ and $A=k[X]$. In fact $R$ is normal since $X(X-1)(X+1)$ has no multiple roots, and $A$ UFD so it's normal. 
$$\Omega_{R/A}\cong \frac{Rdx\oplus Rdy}{(2ydy+(3x^2-1)dx)R}\neq 0$$

(iv) No idea at all.

Comment: By "finite" you mean "finitely generated", right?

Comment: yes, maybe i'll correct this :)

Comment: "finite A-module" has very well defined and universally accepted meaning in algebraic geometry.

Comment: So? any hint to solve it?

Comment: @user213008 What? my example in (iii) without considering differentials, is a clear example that you are wrong. A and B can both be normal, the problem is where they are normal, ie in what fraction field they're normal

Comment: Right, you didn't assume that the the field of fractions of $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic. Sorry, for the confusion. I was thinking about birational morphisms.

Comment: No problem, don't worry :)